# Draft & Published versions

Tags: edit

Does anyone know of a use-case where you can edit a "published version" of an application (or something else), and it duplicates that version in a "Draft version".  Once you click save or publish on the draft version, both files merge and you get one version?

If someone can point me to a similar type of interaction I'd highly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Like forwarding an email and adding a little extra? It's not exactly clear what you're asking for here.

Comment: What would be the point of merging, instead of just publishing the draft? Is the draft an incomplete copy of the published version?

Comment: Interesting. I'm currently working on a system where we just switch status flags on Published things to Edited, then to Published on re-publication. Same object, just a different status. But the published version is still out there for use. I assume that's the norm.

Comment: Although primarily geared around software development, you might want to explore the concept of [**branching**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_(version_control)) that is found in many [**version control systems**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) such as [**Git**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git). These allow "clones" of a file (or, usually, a set of files) to be worked on independently from the "main" version. For plain-text files, they can even merge changes made to both versions (although this isn't always a "magic pill").

Answer (score 1):

I actually worked recently on a feature that performs a similar behavior than you are describing.

It was about a config file, which you can edit and save but (due to backend constraints), once the user clicks on "Save", the changes don't take effect immediately (this action triggers an alert to let know the super admin she has to manually update the file).

So, let's say, there's a while between the user edits the production-config file (and generates a draft) and the moment those changes are deployed to production.

If during this meanwhile the user tries to edit the production-config file, she will access to the draft version (and will be noticed she is seeing a modified-draft version, not the production-running values).